# Search for an array value with keys from another array

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

I have two arrays with nearly the same structure.

The first array is `$_POST` data while the second one holds regex rules and some other stuff for data validation.

Example:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'address' => array(
        'city' => 'Somewhere far beyond'
    )
);

$structure = array(
    'address' => array(
        'city' => array(
             'regex' => 'someregex'
         )
     )
 );
```

Now I want to check

```
$data['address']['city'] with $structure['address']['city']['regex']
```

or

```
$data['foo']['bar']['baz']['xyz']  with $structure['foo']['bar']['baz']['xyz']['regex']
```

Any ideas how to achieve this with a PHP function?

---

Edit: It seems that I found a solution by myself.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'address' => array(
        'city' => 'Somewhere far beyond'
    ),
    'mail' => 'test@test.tld'
);

$structure = array(
    'address' => array(
        'city' => array(
            'regex' => 'some_city_regex1',
        )
    ),
    'mail' => array(
        'regex' => 'some_mail_regex1',
    )
);

function getRegex($data, $structure)
{
    $return = false;

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if (empty($structure[$key])) {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_array($value) && is_array($structure[$key])) {
            getRegex($value, $structure[$key]);
        }
        else {
            if (! empty($structure[$key]['regex'])) {
                echo sprintf('Key "%s" with value "%s" will be checked with regex "%s"', $key, $value, $structure[$key]['regex']) . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

getRegex($data, $structure);
```

Comment: Yes. I'm trying and trying and feeling more and more stupid. :/

Comment: Post what you've tried, so we can show where you went wrong. We're not just going to write it all for you.

Comment: Your function concept is fine. Problems: you don't return anything. Then, explain your desired result: do you want an array of matched results? do you want a True/False global check? Do you want a True/False check for each value? Do you want the matched strings? ...

Comment: @fusion3k It's my plan to use the found value as a parameter for a method call. I have to extend the function above a little more.

Comment: @TeK yes, but in which form? In other words, the above example you want that function returns this array: [ 0=>'Somewhere far beyond' , 1=> 'test@test.tld' ] ?

Comment: @fusion3k In this form the return value will actually be always bool false. Now, I'm using the echoed value as a method parameter. In my case the $structure array is much bigger and holds a bunch of informations about how to treat the incoming $data

Comment: Yes, I suppose that. The point is: your function works. To receive a help you have to specify what is your desired modification, or what is unattended behavior, or what goal you could not reach. Possibly, you have to add to question an example of desired result based on provided arrays examples.

Comment: I asked the question and became 'recursion' as an answer. Look @ the edit in the question. :) Solved my problem already by myself. The function is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given these arrays:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'address' => array(
        'city' => 'Somewhere far beyond'
    ),
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => array(
            'baz' => array(
                'xyz' => 'hij'
            )
        )
    )
);

$structure = array(
    'address' => array(
        'city' => array(
             'regex' => '[a-Z]'
         )
    ),
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => array(
            'baz' => array(
                'xyz' => array(
                    'regex' => '[0-9]+'
                )
            )
        )
    )
 );
```

and this function:

```
function validate ($data, $structure, &$validated) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
            if (
                array_key_exists($key, $structure)
                and is_array($structure[$key])
            ) {             
                if (array_key_exists('regex', $structure[$key])) {
                    if (!preg_match($structure[$key]['regex'])) {
                        $validated = false;
                    }
                }

                validate($value, $structure[$key], $validated);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

you can check the arrays against each other and get a validation result like so:

```
$validated = true;

validate($data, $structure, $validated);

if ($validated) {
    echo 'everything validates!';
}
else {
    echo 'validation error';
}
```

Ah, you've found a solution. Very nice.